# How do I get proper corners of paper by approxPolyDP?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm doing an OCR project by opencv with corner detection and perspective transform in it. It looks quiet successful for certain images of a piece of paper with clear 4 corners. But when I try to figure out the corners with book images, which means there are shadow between the neighbor pages, error comes. Error saids that screenCnts(4 corners from paper image) is not defined. I'm sure that function cv2.approxPolyDP caused this problem. But I can't even imagine how can I always get proper 4 corners. Should I search for another functions to solve this problem?

I made every steps print out their output values and length of output values, and figure out that error-causing images have too many approx values. So I tried to get lesser approx by larger peri's coefficient but then approxs were too less.
Is there perfect coefficient for corner detection?

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200)

(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:4]

for c in cnts :
    peri = cv2.arcLenth(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02*peri, True)

if len(approx) == 4 :
    screenCnt = approx  //threre comes error : NameError name 'screenCnt' is not defined
    break
```

It was planned to gives 4 values from approxPolyDP but some images like books, edge-folded paper, etc has more than 4.
Must be truly appreciate for any help.
https://ibb.co/qCqnFVz link for input image

Comment: Maybe add your input image? :)

Comment: Here's the link for image! https://ibb.co/qCqnFVz